# How to perform multiple LEFT JOIN's in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

Let me describe some background first. We have a table that contains all of our products, and a table that contains a list of 'product tags' (material/size/type), and a table that contains a list of the tags assigned to a product ('tag_id' => 1 (material), 'value' => 'gold', 'product' => 123)

I'm trying to use a query similar to this to filter out certain products, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anybody provide some pointers in the right direction?

```
SELECT DISTINCT `products`.* FROM `products`,`product_assigned_tags`
LEFT JOIN `product_assigned_tags`   AS tags_0 ON tags_0.`tag_id` = 1
LEFT JOIN `product_assigned_tags`   AS tags_1 ON tags_1.`tag_id` = 2
WHERE (
    ((tags_0.`value` = 'silver' ) AND (tags_0.`value` != 'gold' ) ) AND
    ((tags_1.`value` = 'small' ) AND (tags_1.`value` != 'large' ) )
) AND (`products`.`type` = '2' OR `products`.`type` = '1' ) LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: You have an invalid mix of implicit inner joins and left joins. Please post your table structure and a sample of the data you have and would like to query for to help us understand what you're after.

Comment: Best to show your expected output. +1 @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: @Michael: Actually, there aren't any real LEFT joins in the OP query.  The predicates in the WHERE clause negate any "outer"-ness of the "left join", rendering them to be equivalent to "inner join". And that first join is actually a CROSS join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some problems in your query.

First off, you have a CROSS JOIN, which is going to generate a Cartesian product, every row returned from `products` is going to be matched to every row in `product_assigned_tags`.

Also, your next two joins are not actually LEFT joins at all (they are not outer joins), due to the the predicates in the WHERE clause.  The check of `value = 'foo'` is effectively negating the outer join.

Also, some of your predicates are redundant.

If `value = 'silver'` evaluates to true, then `value != 'gold'` is guaranteed to be true, there's no need to include that inequality predicate.

---

It really seems like the `product_assigned_tags` table would be related to a product, with a `product_id` column as a foreign key to `products.id`.  (Absent any schema definition, I'm just making a guess at that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
  FROM `products` p
  JOIN `product_assigned_tags` tags_0
    ON tags_0.product_id = p.id
   AND tags_0.`tag_id` = 1
   AND tags_0.`value` = 'silver'
  JOIN `product_assigned_tags` tags_1 
    ON tags_1.product_id = p.id 
   AND tags_1.`tag_id` = 2
   AND tags_1.`value` = 'small'
 WHERE p.`type` IN ('1','2')
 ORDER BY 1
 LIMIT 0,30
```

---

**Q:**  how would I go about handling an 'OR' case with JOINs? For example: Client has selected to view all products with the material "gold" OR "silver"?

**A:**  express the `OR` conditions in the join predicates, e.g.

```
   AND tags_0.`value` IN ('silver','gold')
```

which is equivalent to:

```
   AND ( tags_0.`value` = 'silver' OR tags_0.`value` = 'gold')
```

Comment: This seems the logical way to do it. However, how would I go about handling an 'OR' case with JOINs?

For example: Client has selected to view all products with the material "gold" OR "silver"?

Comment: @R4wizard: I would express the OR condition in the JOIN predicate.  tags_0.value = 'gold' OR tags_0.value = 'silver'.  Just be sure to enclose that OR expression in parentheses, due to the order of precedence between AND and OR.  Answer updated above.